# Understanding count of logical processing units in Qualcomm SOC

Tags: cpu, arm, cpu-architecture, x86, hyper-threading

I have [Qualcomm RB5 board](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/internet-of-things/industrial/industrial-automation/robotics-rb5-platform).

Its [SOC spec sheet](https://www.qualcomm.com/content/dam/qcomm-martech/dm-assets/documents/qrb5165-soc-product-brief_87-28730-1-b.pdf) says following:

```
CPU: Kryo 585 CPU, 64-bit, up to 2.84 GHz
ISP: Qualcomm Spectra 480 ISP with Dual 14-bit image  signal processing
GPU Adreno 650 GPU w/ support for Open GL ES & Open CL
```

[Product brief link](https://www.qualcomm.com/content/dam/qcomm-martech/dm-assets/documents/qualcomm-robotics-rb5-platform-product-brief.pdf)

The lscpu output is as follows:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       3
Vendor ID:                       Qualcomm
Model:                           14
Stepping:                        0xd
CPU max MHz:                     2841.6001
CPU min MHz:                     300.0000
BogoMIPS:                        38.40
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Vulnerable
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; CSV2, BHB
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atom
                                 ics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm lrcpc dcpop asi
                                 mddp
```

I want to understand meaning of following:

```
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       3
```

I know this is 8 core processor. But I have following questions:

1. By `CPU(s): 8`, does it mean it has 8 cores?
2. Socket * Cores per socket = 3 * 2 = 6. Why it differs from 8?
3. Does this mean that total number of logical cores = 3 * 2 * 8 = 48?

Answer (score 1):

The CPU has got 8 cores (4 "big" high performance, 4 "little" low power), numbered 0 through 7. All cores are single threaded, no SMT - logical cores = physical cores. The *cores per socket* and *sockets* values are nonsense, it's only a single socket.

My guess is that virtual sockets are used to distinguish between big and little cores. Why 3*2 = 6 cores are indicated instead of 8 is beyond me. Possibly there are 2 sockets with 2 (big+little) cores each and 1 socket for the DSP.

Comment: So there is no logical vs physical processor distinction in this? All it has is just 8 physical cores, 4 big and 4 little, right?

Comment: The Kryo 585 actually contains 3 core groups. One premium "big" core, 3 standard "big" cores and 4 "little" cores. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryo#Kryo_500_Series `1x Kryo 585 Prime @ up to 3.2 GHz + 3x Kryo 585 Gold @ 2.42 GHz + 4x Kryo 585 Silver @ 1.80 GHz` so the sockets appear to be the three processor complexes, but I don't know why it says 2 cores per socket. Possibly because with the 1,3,4 complex there is no useful same number across the core complexes. At best "2" is the rounded down average number of cores per socket, 8 cores across 3 sockets being 2.666666 cores per socket.

Comment: @Mokubai That would a very reasonable explanation - I don't see the 'premium' core in the linked docs though. That might be true only for the *Prime* model.

Comment: @Zac67 a datasheet for a device containing the specific QRB5165 shows the three core groups as well, just with slower clock on the prime core: https://cdn.lantronix.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/MPB-00118-RevB-Open-Q-5165RB.pdf so I suspect any 585 based SoM to be the same.

Comment: As another data point Qualcomms own documentation at https://docs.qualcomm.com/bundle/publicresource/topics/80-PV086-5P/QRB5165-features.html?product=Robotics%20RB5%20Development%20Kit does spend a lot of time saying that there are only 4 "gold" and 4 "silver" cores but the specific features page breaks the 4 gold cores down as 1 "prime gold" and 3 "gold" cores. I do not see any model specific variant information amongst that documentation.